# Reusing a function for buttons that work independently of each other?

Tags: audio, p5.js

I'm trying to create something with P5.js that resembles an audio looper—that is, you record a snippet of audio, it plays back to you as a loop, and then you can record other snippets of audio to play together to create a song.

I figured out how to record audio, play it back as a loop, and stop the loop, but I'm not sure the best way to repeat that function so that it can be used for buttons that function independently of each other and record separate audio files, as I would like to record multiple loops.

I'm still pretty new to P5.js, so there's probably a simple way to do this—any ideas help! In general, if you have any ideas on how to achieve this project as a whole (the audio looper) I'd love to hear them.

This is my code:

```
let mic, recorder, soundFile, button;

let state = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(200);
  mic = new p5.AudioIn();
  mic.start();
  recorder = new p5.SoundRecorder();
  recorder.setInput(mic);
  soundFile = new p5.SoundFile();

  button = createButton("record");

  button.size(200, 100);
  button.style("font-family", "Bodoni");
  button.style("font-size", "48px");

  button.position(10, 10, 10);
  button.mouseClicked(loopRecord);
}


// this is the looper
function loopRecord() {
  if (state === 0 && mic.enabled) {
    recorder.record(soundFile);

    background(255, 0, 0);
    state++;
  } else if (state === 1) {
    recorder.stop();

    background(0, 255, 0);
    state++;
  } else if (state === 2) {
    soundFile.loop();
    state++;
  } else if (state === 3) {
    soundFile.stop();
    state++;
  } else if (state === 4) {
    state === 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should somehow structure your data so that each button has its own state (and other parameters that should not be global, but instead unique to each loop).

Here an example using an array of track objects:
https://editor.p5js.org/RemyDekor/sketches/gM75vBYmk

I'll copy the code here as well

```js
let mic

// this array will be filled afterwards
let tracksArray = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  background(200);
  
  // we need only one mic (it is still global)
  mic = new p5.AudioIn();
  mic.start();
  
  // we call a function that creates a custom "track" object and puts it in the tracksArray (which you could use for some other things, but is currently un-used)
  createTrack();
  
  // we create a button that call the same function when we click on it
  const addTrackButton = createButton("add track");
  addTrackButton.mouseClicked(createTrack)
  addTrackButton.position(10, 10)
}

// We now use names (strings) instead of abstract numbers to set the state of the track
function handleTrackButtonClick(trackObject) {
  if (trackObject.state === "idle" && mic.enabled) {
    trackObject.recorder.record(trackObject.soundFile);
    background(255, 0, 0);
  
    trackObject.state = "recording";
    console.dir(trackObject.button.elt.innerText = "[recording..]");
    
  } else if (trackObject.state === "recording") {
    trackObject.recorder.stop();
    background(0, 255, 0);
    
    trackObject.state = "stopped";
    console.dir(trackObject.button.elt.innerText = "play");
  
  } else if (trackObject.state === "stopped") {
    trackObject.soundFile.loop();
    
    trackObject.state = "playing";
    console.dir(trackObject.button.elt.innerText = "[playing..] stop")
    
  } else if (trackObject.state === "playing") {
    trackObject.soundFile.stop();
    
    trackObject.state = "stopped";
    console.dir(trackObject.button.elt.innerText = "[stopped..] play")
  }
}


function createTrack() {
  const newButton = createButton("record");
  newButton.style("font-family", "Bodoni");
  newButton.style("font-size", "48px");
  // we do not position this button anymore, and use the "flow" of the html document
  newButton.style("display", "block");
  
  // this is the "track" object we create, and we attach the previously global parameters/states on it
  const newTrackObject = {
    button: newButton,
    state: "idle",
    recorder: new p5.SoundRecorder(),
    soundFile: new p5.SoundFile()
  };
  
  newButton.mouseClicked(function() {
     handleTrackButtonClick(newTrackObject)
  });
  
  newTrackObject.recorder.setInput(mic);
  
  tracksArray.push(newTrackObject);
}
```